# Excel VBA Lookup Methods

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-2007, match, vlookup

I have an issue that I've been scratching my head at; I've looked into the `Index:Match` lookup method, and `V/HLookup`, but I'm not sure these will help just yet. Here's what's happening:

I have two worksheets in [excel-2007](/questions/tagged/excel-2007). One has a Customer ID column (which does and will have duplicate ID's in the instance that the customer did "x activity" more than one time in a month) and then the date that this happened in another column. The second sheet is for giving an overview of a specific day, IE what happened on 7-1-13.

The issue is that my raw data sheet is sorted via the first of the month descending, so 7-1,7-2,etc, and when I run the `Vlookup`, if a Customer ID has a record on 7-2 and on 7-15, the `VLookup` will pull data only from the 7-2 (first) row. Has anyone experienced this and found a workaround?

My current workaround would be to make either a new table for each day's data, or instead of using my `VLookup` of `=Vlookup(A2, 'Data Sheet' A:D, 4, 0)` to give the columns row numbers, like `=Vlookup(A2, 'Data Sheet' A$1:D$30, 4, 0)`. This is a daily report, and that would be intense. Please help if you can!

(Another side note, I have one main sheet for the view, one data sheet where it's all collected, and then 30 sheets, one for each day of the month, this case being July). For each sheet, I've named them the day of the month, so I'm reflecting the data as such:

Sheets("7-1-13") has data from the 1st on it. The Data Sheet in it's entireity has data from 7-1-13 to 7-31-13. I need to reference ID's on the 1st to the data for the 1st and the 1st only.

I want to use something like this, but I'm having a hard time with it

```
=Vlookup(A2, 'Data Sheet', A:D (ONLY IF THE CREATE DATE OF THIS ITEM IS 7-1), 4,0)`
```

but of course it's not that easy :p

Comment: It can be a unique value, but isn't always...For instance, a Customer ID of "1009" can do something on the 1st and the 15th under the same ID

Comment: I know, this is a tricky situation. I'll post an example book in a couple of hours, work is about to be over, and this way I can create a mock up version. I'll post it once it's online.

Answer (score 0):

This may not give you your results in a format you like and still requires a bit of manual work, but without going the route of macros, I think this will get you one step closer. I thought of using an array formula to get all the IDs by a specific date.

Example:

```
        A    B
       ID   Date
1      5    7/1/2013
2      2    7/2/2013
3      5    7/3/2013
```

In this situation, I assume you want 5 from the first row to appear on your 7/1 sheet, 2 to appear on your 7/2 sheet, and 5 from the third row to appear on your 7/3 sheet

on your 7/1 sheet. you'll need to select the number of blank rows that matches your raw data (using the example above, you would be selecting A1:A3 on your 7/1 sheet). Once you have your cells selected, then enter the following formula in the formula bar ***and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter***. This is what makes the formula an array formula.

```
=((Raw_DataSheet!B1:B3=DATE(2013,7,1))*1)*Raw_DataSheet!A1:A3
```

What this formula does is looks at all the dates in B1:B3 and finds the ones that equal 7/1/2013. Since you're using an array formula, this gives you the array {TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}. Multiply this by 1, and you get the array {1,0,0}. You now have an array that has a 1 for each row of B1:B3 that was equal to 7/1/2013. This array {1,0,0} is then multiplied by your Customer IDs {5,2,5}

```
5 * 1  =  5
2 * 0  =  0
5 * 0  =  0
```

So now your entire formula is equal to the array {5,0,0}. Since you selected A1:A3 on your 7/1 sheet, the values that should appear should be

```
        A 
       ID 
1      5 
2      0 
3      0
```

From here, you can always filter out the 0's and you'd just have a list of all the IDs that had the date of 7/1 from your Raw Data Sheet. You would also then replicate this for each of your sheets and just change the date in the formula...Yes, I know, way more complicated than you probably wanted but it's what I came up with!